# RapidSVN Unable to connect to a repository

Tags: svn

I was using my RapidSVN for last year just fine, and today at some point it just stopped working. I mean I used to commit a change to a file, and then commit on a different file and all the sudden this started. All this SVN was not set up by me, so I don't know how to manage it. Where should I start?

Here is the error:

```
Execute: Commit
Error: Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow):
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://server.domainname.com/domainname.com'
Ready
```

Answer (score 0):

That error generally means that your Subversion client and the server can no longer communicate successfully, perhaps due to a network outage.  Do you get this error from multiple systems, or only from yours?  Do you always get this error message, or is it intermittent?  Can you access the server using something other than Subversion (ssh, telnet, etc)?  Is the `svnserve` process still running on the server?  Is there anything useful in the server logs?

Comment: It's all fixed now. Turns out that problem started when server went down for couple minutes and SVN daemon stopped working...